# Can you add a fifth TPMS sensor to a GMC Savana 3500?

Tags: gmc, tire-pressure-monitoring-system, savanna

I have a small truck built on a 2013 GMC Savana 3500 cutaway. I recently got new tires and the tire shop saved the best of the old tires so I could have a spare. I ordered an new wheel to install the tire on and I am trying to find out if I can add the spare tire to the TPMS. My truck has single rear wheels and the tire pressure shows up on the dashboard display. The truck is available with duallies, which implies the computer can support six sensors.

My tire shop said "we do whatever the computer prompts us to do". Is it possible to add just a fifth tire to this system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no, you can't have a 5th TPMS sensor on your spare and have the system recognize it. The reason for this is, it's only setup for four sensors. When resetting the sensors, you go around to each tire as indicated by the turn signal lighting up and "learn" the sensor at that corner. There's no 5th sensor for it to check, only the four. This doesn't mean you can't have a sensor on your spare, it just means the system isn't going to recognize it.

**NOTE:** This is true for GM vehicles with the four corner sensoring. Other manufacturers could do it differently.

Comment: Does that mean if it has duallies, it would still only have 4 sensors?

Comment: TBH, I'm not sure how the duallies work. According to [this forum post](https://www.dieselplace.com/threads/tpms-on-dually.388151/), vehicles over 10,000lb GVWR are not required to have a TPMS system. I'm pretty sure 3500 (typically called "1 ton") vehicles will be over this GVWR and won't have a TPMS on it. The post also suggests dually vehicles from GM do not come with a TPMS from the factory.